# How to preview cart when mouseover My Cart in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, xml, magento, preview, cart

I've tried to use the extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Vitalityshop/extension/6424/cartview
but it's not working out for me.

Tried Google how to but there are relatively very few posts on this topic. And no answers solved my problem.

So how do I display the items in my cart when mouseover the My Cart button in the top links?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different extensions which do this including [my own](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/15566/s/ajax-cart-popup-9931/), but in simple terms what you need to do is add a block to the page inside which you render your mini cart, then display/hide that block as you rollover the my cart link using a JS event listener on the relevant element.